# How can I export and import all emails from Google Apps/Workspace to Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

How can I export and import all emails from Google Apps/Workspace to Gmail

Export all emails from 1 Google Apps/Workspace account

Import into 1 gmail account

Comment: I did this a couple of years ago and found that using POP3 to connect to the old account causes too many problems (spam filtering, loss of labels, everything marked as unread). In the end, I connected both accounts using IMAP to the Thunderbird mail client and dragged and dropped the contents of each IMAP folder from the old to the new account.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `imapsync` regularly to backup my emails from my main Google Apps (legacy, free as in beer, version) to other email server (dovecot on Linux). I used this tool to do similar backup from the same account to regular GMail account a few years back.

Comment: This is Linux? ….././

Comment: Yes. But imapsync is just perl script AFAIR, you may be able to also run it on Windows.